# Needed absolute value of field in Oracle BIPublisher desktop

Tags: oracle

I found this function absolute value which works for number, but doesn't work for field even if I set the field to be Number, or I use conversion TO_NUMBER.

```
<?xdoxslt:abs(-123.45)?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We found solution: Value in the Advanced tab first converted to number and the absolute value. Like this:

```
<?xdoxslt:abs(xdoxslt:to_number(D_LINE_UNIT_SELLING_PRICE))?>
```